# Is there a rigorous textbook on step by step development for coming up with the equations of motion of classical dynamical systems?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, dynamical-systems, physics, classical-mechanics

I was trying to find some references for modelling the equations of motion of a simple dynamical system (say a pendulum on a moving mass) when I realized that the very vast majority of the material you find online or even in textbooks suffer from the following problems:

1. Reference frame poorly defined, wildly assigned or even implicit. No idea which point is considered to be origin, which direction positive, etc.
2. Free body diagram completely unprincipled and/or confusing.
3. Confusion between magnitude of a vector (e.g., Force) and the vector itself (not mentioning switching back and forth)
4. No general form for basic laws of motion. Sometimes when the authors apply Newton's second law, for instance, they are applying it implicitly along some dimension.
5. Constants are stated and used without derivation or motivation, e.g., moment of inertia are mysterious constants that you would look up from a table

And many more problems.

Does there exist any textbook on modeling classical dynamical systems (pendulum, masses, multi-link robot) from scratch?

Comment: it would be nice to have a reference, but I suspect you won’t find a very detailed dynamical systems text because math books don’t focus so much on deriving the equations themselves, and physics books at the university level already expect you to be able to fill in the blanks, so these are mostly left as exercises (especially for pendulums, springs, moments of inertias of ‘standard’ bodies). I guess you could take a look at Sears and Zemansky’s text, which is meant for introductory physics (I recall reading it in middle and high school, and I understood things more clearly after that).

Comment: but really once you have more complicated systems (double/triple pendulum, or pendulum with springs etc), the default is just to write down a Lagrangian and churn out the Euler-Lagrange equations.

Comment: Maybe [**Mechanics**](http://pldml.icm.edu.pl/pldml/element/bwmeta1.element.dl-catalog-50796184-5cd5-4064-b87f-71e6fecb3d49) by Stefan Banach (1951). Yes, THAT Banach. Freely available chapter .pdf files at bottom of the web page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field of [analytical mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytical_mechanics) is devoted to this.
Most prominently, the [Lagrange formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics), the [Hamilton formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics), and the [Hamilton–Jacobi formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation) are ways to deduce equations of motion in a systematic manner.

Analytical mechanics is usually a major part of courses on theoretical mechanics, which are part of the standard physics curriculum (at least in my country). Any decent textbook on theoretical mechanics should therefore at least be a good starting point on this topic.